# Shortcut in Notepad++ to switch between search box and main window (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

Is any of you know if there is a systematic keyboard shortcut to switch back to the main window from the search box in Windows 7 (either from Notepad++ side, or Windows 7 side)?

Of course, you could do Alt+Tab but you might not end up directly on the right window (you might have to do "Alt+Tab" several times).

The idea to use Win+ to switch between windows does not work because the search box is not recognized as a dedicated window.

Thanks

PS: I have asked this question in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398298/shortcut-in-notepad-to-switch-between-search-box-and-main-window-windows-7?noredirect=1#comment34064420_22398298) but I just realized it would be more appropriate in SuperUser.

Comment: Are you asking about the notepad++ internal search window or the windows search window?

Comment: The Notepad++ internal search window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not such shortcut. The only thing that comes to mind, that is a bit complicated, but still a keyboard "shortcut" is the following: Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, releasing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. When you go back to Notepad++ with the second switch, the search dialog is no longer on focus. That, however, is bothersome as it switches between programs. You can also do the following, although I am not sure it's any less of a hassle: Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> once, without releasing <kbd>Alt</kbd> hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, then release <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>. The focus goes back to the main window. Not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Good suggestion